# How do I create a BaaN interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, erp

What is the best way to create an interface to the **BaaN MRP** system?

I'm looking for a way to use C# to create an interface to update the inventory at the ERP.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Looks like BaaN is not officially supported anymore. The system is now owned by a different company and it's dead now.

Comment: That is definitely not true, the product is not dead.  The Baan Company has merged (via Invensys) into SSA Global and that into [Infor](http://www.infor.com).  The BaaN product has been rebranded into [Infor ERP LN](http://www.infor.com/product_summary/erp/ln/).  Infor ERP LN is a major product line of Infor, and is still being sold, supported, and enhanced as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a com reference to /baan/bin/bw.tlb 
(Ole Automation Baan Type Library)

Answer (score 0):

```
object Baan = null ;
Type t;
t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Baan4.Application.someuser");
Baan = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
object[] Parameters = new Object[1];
Parameters[0] = 3600;

//Baan.Timeout = 3600;
Baan.GetType().InvokeMember("Timeout", 
                            BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
                            null, 
                            Baan, 
                            Parameters
);

Parameters = new Object[2];
Parameters[0] = "otccomdll...";
Parameters[1] = "function.name...";
Baan.GetType().InvokeMember("ParseExecFunction", 
                             BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                             null, 
                             Baan, 
                             Parameters
);
//your code here    
//Baan.Quit();
Baan.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Baan, null);
```

Comment: Do I need Baan library or some other reference to be able to use the Baan object in C#?